# Let $A, B, C$ be sets. Prove that $A \cap (B - C) = (A \cap B) - (A \cap C).$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Let $A, B,$ and $C$ be sets. Prove that $A \cap (B - C) = (A\cap B) - (A \cap C).$

I know where I'd start for a union but the intersection is confusing me.

Comment: Start from the definition, if $x\in A\cap (B-C)$, what must happen?

Answer (score 2):

*Proof:* Let $A, B$ and $C$ be any sets. To prove that $A \cap (B - C) = (A \cap B) - (A \cap C),$ we must prove that $A \cap (B - C) \subseteq (A \cap B) - (A \cap C)$ and that $(A \cap B) - (A \cap C) \subseteq A \cap (B - C).$

$\subseteq.$ Let $x \in A \cap (B - C).$ Then $x \in A$ and $x \in B - C.$ Since $x \in B - C,$ we deduce that $x \in B$ and $x \notin C.$ We have that $x \in A$ and $x \in B,$ hence $x \in A \cap B.$ Since $x \notin C,$ then $x \notin A \cap C.$ So $x \in (A \cap B) - (A \cap C).$ Therefore $A \cap (B - C) \subseteq (A \cap B) - (A \cap C).$

$\supseteq.$ Let $x \in (A \cap B) - (A \cap C).$ Then $x \in A \cap B$ and $x \notin A \cap C.$ Since $x \in A \cap B,$ we conclude that $x \in A$ and $x \in B.$ Given that $x \notin A \cap C$ and that $x \in A,$ we deduce that $x \notin C.$ Because $x \in B$ and $x \notin C,$ we have that $x \in B - C.$ Since $x \in A,$ it follows that $x \in A \cap (B - C).$ Therefore $(A \cap B) - (A \cap C) \subseteq A \cap (B - C).$

Since $(A \cap B) - (A \cap C) \subseteq A \cap (B - C) \subseteq (A \cap B) - (A \cap C),$ we conclude that $A \cap (B - C) = (A \cap B) - (A \cap C).$ $\square$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $A,B,C$ belong to $U,$
$$A\cap (B-C)=(A \cap B)- (A \cap C)$$
**RHS:**
$$(A \cap B)- (A \cap C) = (A \cap B)\cap(A \cap C)^c$$
$$=(A \cap B)\cap(A^c \cup C^c)$$
$$=(A \cap B \cap A^c)\cup(A \cap B \cap C^c)$$
$$=(A \cap B \cap C^c)$$

**LHS:**
$$ A\cap (B−C)= A \cap (B \cap C^C)=(A \cap B \cap C^C)$$

As, $\text{LHS}=\text{RHS},$ the given equality holds true.

If I've missed out anything, please let me know, Thanks!